# How to specify user account to only specific webpages using PHP

Tags: php

I have this below PHP code that restrict users with level 2 or higher to be able to see this specific webpages.

But I want to restrict it only for users with level 2 and level 7 for this webpages as I have users with level 1, 3 and 4 as well, (level 7 is admin).

I don't want user with 1,3 or 4 to be able to log into this webpages. I have tried with "==2 || == 7" but I can't get that to work correctly.

How to write the PHP code for this to work properly?

```
                <!-- User with account type 2 or higher  -->
                <!-- But want user with account type 2 and 7 only  -->

        <?php if (Session::get("user_account_type") >=2 ): ?>
                <li <?php if (View::checkForActiveController($filename, "project")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
                <a>Projekt</a>
            <ul class="navigation-submenu">
                <li <?php if (View::checkForActiveController($filename, "project")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
                    <a href="<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>project/alfa">Project Alfa</a>
                </li>
                <li <?php if (View::checkForActiveController($filename, "project")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
                    <a href="<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>project/delta">Project Delta</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </li>            
        <?php endif; ?>
```

This is the admin level page

```
            <!-- User with admin level 7  -->

        <?php if (Session::get("user_account_type") == 7) : ?>
            <li <?php if (View::checkForActiveController($filename, "admin")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
                <a href="<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>admin/">Admin</a>
            </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
```

Comment: *"I have tried with "==2 || == 7""* - What is the actual syntax you used? Seeing that, suggests you probably didn't use it correctly. The syntax in general is `if(condition) == x or (condition) == y` type of thing.

Comment: If I use ' <?php if (Session::get("user_account_type") ==2 or ("user_account_type") ==7  ): ?>' The admin user can not see the webpage...

Comment: Try this instead: `<?php if (Session::get("user_account_type") ==2) or (Session::get("user_account_type") ==7 ): ?>`, could just be a bracketing issue. I don't know which framework you're using, so there could be a specific way that needs to be used.

Comment: Not working as I get this error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'or' (T_LOGICAL_OR) in /storage/content/60/238760/webpage.com/application/view/_templates/header.php

Comment: Then try `<?php if (Session::get("user_account_type") ==2 or (Session::get("user_account_type") ==7 )): ?>`. That ought to do it. Edit: Try `||` instead of `OR` `<?php if (Session::get("user_account_type") ==2 ||  (Session::get("user_account_type") ==7 )): ?>`.

Comment: YES :) it did, thanks, I did try lots of different ways but not this one... great

Comment: Welcome, glad to hear it. Would you like me to post it as the answer so it can be marked as solved/closed?

Comment: Yes case is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"I have tried with "==2 || == 7" but I can't get that to work correctly."*

That is because you need to use 2 separate conditions. The way you say you tried it, was invalid/incorrect syntax.

Use the following as I outlined in comments:

```
<?php if (Session::get("user_account_type") ==2 
      or (Session::get("user_account_type") ==7 )): ?>
```

or using the `||` (OR) logical operator which is (basically) the same.

```
<?php if (Session::get("user_account_type") ==2 
      || (Session::get("user_account_type") ==7 )): ?>
```